# Find the position of a key in a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$actualPlan = 'medium';

$plans = array(
    array(
        'plans'    => array(
            'tiny'   => 29,
            'small'  => 69,
            'medium' => 179,
            'big'    => 359
        )
    )
);
```

During a foreach, I display the contents of `plans` of this array like this:

```
foreach($plans as $key => $data) {
    foreach($data['plans'] as $plan => $rate) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But how can I know the position of the `$actualPlan` ?

For example, for :

if `$actualPlan == medium` it should return me `3`.

if `$actualPlan == tiny` it should return me `1`.

Thanks.

Comment: make a new array of position with plan as key and position as value

Comment: The order of elements in an array like this are not guaranteed.

Comment: @ryantxr, could you please explain more ?

Comment: You cannot rely on the position of a certain key in an array. The order is not guaranteed.

Comment: It's not more informations than your first message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside the loop:

```
echo array_search($actualPlan, array_keys($rate)); // returns the index position as int
```

here will output 1,2,3,4 for the inputs 'tiny','small','medium','big'

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I tried to make my question more generic. Hope it will help you.

Comment: It works with `array_keys($data['plans'])` at the end rather than `array_keys($rate)`.

Answer (score 0):

Within the `foreach($plans as $key => $data) {`, you could make the conditional like this :

```
$current_plan = explode('___', $actualPlan);
$current_key = array_search($current_plan[0],array_keys($data['plans']));

foreach($data['plans'] as $plan => $rate) {
    $current_iterated_key = array_search($plan,array_keys($data['plans']));
    if ($current_iterated_key < $current_key) {
        echo "$plan => Downgrade\r\n";
    } elseif ($current_iterated_key > $current_key) {
        echo "$plan => Upgrade\r\n";
    } elseif($current_iterated_key == $current_key) {
        echo "$plan => Current\r\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I edited my answer because it turns out using the `switch()` statements actually  didn't work, I changed it using `if else` instead..